# Angular5 service to get a custom query string parameter

Tags: angular, routes

In AngularJs if I want to get a query string parameter, I can use the `$rootScope` and check for a parameter and store it in the session, so that no matter where I go in the application, it will persist.
I am trying to do a similar thing in Angular 5.

I have created this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

import { SessionService } from './session.service';

@Injectable()
export class QueryStringService {
  key: string = 'options';
  options = {
    debugging: false
  };

  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) { }

  init(paramMap: ParamMap): void {
    // Get any saved session and our query parameters
    var session = this.sessionService.get(this.key);
    var debug = paramMap.get('debug');

    // If we have a saved session, updates our options
    if (session) Object.assign(this.options, session);

    // If we have any query parameters set, update our options
    if (debug === '1') this.options.debugging = true;    

    console.log(paramMap.get('debug'));
    console.log(this.options);

    // Save our options in the session
    this.sessionService.save(this.key, this.options);
  }
}
```

I put this in my **AppComponent** like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { QueryStringService } from './core/services/query-string.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'piiick-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private queryStringService: QueryStringService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      this.queryStringService.init(paramMap);
    });
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I assume it's because it doesn't have a route assigned to the **AppComponent**. I could add it to each Component throughout the site, but I was hoping someone knows of a global way of handling this.